# Reset Counter in While Loop

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

I would like to reset counter in the following loop. Have no idea how to do it

```
$j = 1; 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($check)) { 
$value = $row['tmpi'];

$calculate = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM tmpi_db WHERE  tmpi_id = '".value."'");  

$action = mysqli_num_rows($calculate); 


if($j == $action) {

//RESET $j, $j must be one again, nothing is working I have tried $j = 1;
//It's keep incrementing 1,2,3,4,5,6,7.....
}

}
$j++
```

Please help

Comment: look into if ($j== $action) {$j=1; break;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work. Simply start at zero, increment it in beginning and reset the `$j` if the action occurs, the next time it loops the `$j` will increment again and be in zero configuration (i.e. contain value 1):

```
$j = 0; 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($check))
{
    $j++;
    $value = $row['tmpi'];
    $calculate = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM tmpi_db WHERE  tmpi_id = '".value."'");
    $action = mysqli_num_rows($calculate); 
    if($j == $action)
    {
        $j = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just move your `$j++` in an else section eg

```
if($j == $action){
 //stuff and reset
}else{
 $j++;
}
```

Comment: Now it's not incrementing it's 0 all the time

Comment: Then you're doing something very wrong and it shouldn't have worked in the first place or you broke it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
if($j == $action) i{
    //your code
    $j=0;
} else {
    $j++;
}
```